# fabricjs change cursor for every object

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I created some objects with fabric js and added different cursors for them if the user hovers with his mouse over the object. i want to add a function which changes the cursor for the whole canvas and all its objects and then changes it back to its default values (so the cursor settings for the objects and the canvas).

is there a way to do this simple? or do i have to set the cursor for every object manually?
I got a small jsFiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/bxgox7cr/14/

If you click on the button "change Cursor", the cursor is changed to a crosshair, but when you move your mose over the lines or circles, it is changed to their settings. I want the cursor to stay as a crosshair. After pressing "default Cursor" all the settings should be set back, so the cursor should use the special settings for lines and circles.

the main functionality is in this 2 functions:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    canvas.defaultCursor = 'crosshair';
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
    canvas.defaultCursor = 'default';
});
```

I might save the default values for every object and then change them back after the click of button2, but this seems to be a difficult solution, so I'm hoping there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your code this event:

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(event){
    if (event.target != null)
    event.target.hoverCursor = canvas.defaultCursor;
  }
});
```

On each object you will reset 'hover' cursor what you set for whole canvas.

**Updated:**

If you need reset to default you have to keep track of original cursors for each object. You need something like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    changeCursor('crosshair');
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
    resetCursor();
});

var cursors = {canvasDefault: canvas.defaultCursor,
      canvasDefault: 'default',
      object:[
        {objectType: 'circle',
        hoverCursor: 'move'},
        {objectType: 'line',
        hoverCursor: 'ns-resize'}
      ]
      };

function changeCursor(cursor){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){ 
  for (var i in cursors.object){
    if (cursors.object[i].objectType == obj.type){
        obj.hoverCursor = cursor;
    }
  }
    canvas.defaultCursor = cursor;
  });
}

function resetCursor(){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){ 
  for (var i in cursors.object){
    if (cursors.object[i].objectType == obj.type){
        obj.hoverCursor = cursors.object[i].hoverCursor;
    }
  }
    canvas.defaultCursor = cursors.canvasDefault;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey Observer, 
thanks for your reply. 
I tried this but this will reset the whole Cursor, I wanted it to change to a crosshair for every object, but after the "default" button back to its own properties (so default for the canvas, "ns-resize" for the lines, etc..
is this possible or do I have to save the settings somewhere for every object?